# Relationship for the real-value A and C given the medium B?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, real-numbers

I wonder that for

> Given scenario 1: A ≥ B ≈ C

> Given scenario 2: A ≈ B ≥ C

Can we conclude any relationship between A and C for each of the scenario?

Thanks to the fruitful comments, I now add an extra condition that: |B - C| <  for some small  > 0 in Scenario 1, and |A - B| <  for some small  > 0 in Scenario 2.

P.S. I recalled that I saw a symbol with "≈" on top of ">", does this one the same as ⪆?

Comment: Hi! As stated, this problem is too vague to answer. You should decide for yourself what $A \approx B$ means. Then see if you can come up with a counterexample.

Comment: I don't think $⪆$ is a universally-defined symbol, so whether we can conclude $A ⪆ B$ depends on the context. If you want something a little more formal/rigorous, I would likely interpret $B \approx C$ as $|B - C| < \varepsilon$ for some small $\varepsilon > 0$, representing some allowable tolerance of error. If we also have $|A - B| < \varepsilon$ as well, then from our two inequalities, we could conclude that $A > B - 2\varepsilon$. It doesn't mean $A \ge B$, but it does mean $A \ge B$ "up to a little bit", where the little bit is $2\varepsilon$.

Comment: @TheoBendit Thanks mate! My bad, these two scenarios actually independent. So, if we have |  −  | < , we only have B ≥ C instead of |  −  | < . Under your notation, can we still conclude some relation for A and C for each of the independent scenario? Many thanks.

Comment: @BrianTung Thanks for the suggestion! I'm just a newbie to math, just recently something come up in my head, and I wonder such things hhh.

Comment: What is your mathematical background? Do you know calculus or real analysis?

Comment: @user21820 Hi mate, yeah, I attend some lectures for these two things in uni years ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define "≈" as part of asymptotic notation, like "A ≈ B as t → x" meaning "A−B ∈ o(1) as t → x", then you can indeed prove nice properties such as:

- If A ≈ B ≈ C as t → x, then A ≈ C as t → x.
- If A ≥ B ≈ C as t → x, then ( A > C or A ≈ C ) as t → x.
- If A ≈ B ≥ C as t → x, then ( A > C or A ≈ C ) as t → x.

You could define "A ⪆ C" to mean "A > C or A ≈ C", which simplifies the notation of the last two facts. Note that ( A ⪆ C as t → x ) is equivalent to ( A>C+o(1) as t → x ).

Comment: Thanks for the thoughtful reply! It inspires me something more!

Comment: @sharp_flyingrain: Note that you can get to the desired results by another path: First prove that ( A ≥ B as t → x ) ⇒ ( A > B+o(1) as t → x ), which is trivial since 0 > −abs(t−x) for t ≠ x. It is also trivial that ( A ≈ B as t → x ) ⇒ ( A > B+o(1) as t → x ). Now it is obvious that ( ( A > B+o(1) and B > C+o(1) ) as t → x ) ⇒ ( A > C+o(1) ) as t → x ).